# Can someone explain this Stracktrace from a kernel error?

Tags: kernel, crash

PC Info:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Ryzen 5 3600
- Nvidia RTX 2060 Super

Context:

I'm trying to debug a problem where the display output of my PC is suddenly freezing and the last second of played Audio gets looped over and over again.

I'm currently in the elimination process and got this stacktrace in `/var/log/syslog`.
I'm hoping someone more experienced could explain what this stacktrace is telling.

```
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702607] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702612] corrupted preempt_count: swapper/0/0/0x1
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702617] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at kernel/sched/core.c:5011 finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x1f6/0x290
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702625] Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock vmw_vmci vboxdrv(OE) nvidia_uvm(PO) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common nvidia_drm(PO) edac_mce_amd nvidia_modeset(PO) kvm_amd ccp kvm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel nvidia(PO) crypto_simd cryptd snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event nls_iso8859_1 snd_rawmidi rapl snd_seq snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper snd_timer wmi_bmof ucsi_ccg snd k10temp fb_sys_fops typec_ucsi syscopyarea sysfillrect typec sysimgblt soundcore joydev input_leds mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ramoops pstore_blk reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul nvme i2c_nvidia_gpu i2c_piix4 r8169 ahci i2c_ccgx_ucsi xhci_pci
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702677]  nvme_core libahci realtek xhci_pci_renesas wmi
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702681] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: P           OE     5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702683] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7C37/MPG X570 GAMING PLUS (MS-7C37), BIOS A.B0 10/29/2020
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702685] RIP: 0010:finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x1f6/0x290
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702687] Code: 09 00 00 48 8d b0 98 0b 00 00 48 c7 c7 70 c7 7f 96 c6 05 19 dc 28 02 01 65 8b 0d d5 29 f1 6a 81 e1 ff ff ff 7f e8 0a 5d d4 00 <0f> 0b 65 8b 0d c1 29 f1 6a 89 ca 89 c8 81 e2 00 00 00 80 83 ca 02
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702689] RSP: 0018:ffffffff97003dd0 EFLAGS: 00010046
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702691] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702692] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702693] RBP: ffffffff97003df8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702694] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff930094ac6600
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702695] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff930094ac6600 R15: ffff9302dea31280
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702696] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9302dea00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702697] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702698] CR2: 00007f36fd200038 CR3: 000000011dd00000 CR4: 0000000000350ef0
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702700] Call Trace:
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702702]  <TASK>
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702705]  __schedule+0x25f/0x5d0
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702709]  schedule_idle+0x2a/0x50
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702711]  do_idle+0xb9/0x110
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702713]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702714]  rest_init+0xe5/0x100
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702717]  ? acpi_enable_subsystem+0x20b/0x225
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702721]  arch_call_rest_init+0xe/0x1d
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702724]  start_kernel+0x4b3/0x4e4
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702727]  x86_64_start_reservations+0x24/0x2c
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702729]  x86_64_start_kernel+0xee/0x103
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702731]  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xe5/0xeb
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702735]  </TASK>
May 26 20:47:54 philipp-MS-7C37 kernel: [ 2682.702736] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

EDIT 10-06-2023:

Since posting the Question i have been able to reproduce this issue with a different set of RAM, also my original RAM did not fail in a Memtest with multiple Runs.

I am currently in the process of trying to reproduce this error with a different graphics card. Graphics Driver have been switched already with no luck.

Comment: Just would like to add that I am not on Ubuntu, but Arch Linux and I am experiencing the same issue with a Ryzen 5 3600, I have tried turning off global C states, turned off any extra CPU settings like virtualization and nothing works, I still receive random hangs from everything in the same error format. Try to also run a memtest86 overnight to double check your RAM.

Comment: I have already eliminated the RAM as you can see in my edit.

Comment: To anyone who stumbles acorss this:
I ended up eliminating every component and was left with a faulty CPU.
Upgraded to a R5 5600 - no Crashes since 1.5 months.